# Running camera calibration node in Raspberry pi in ROS Indigo

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros, camera-calibration

I am following this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) for calibrating raspberry pi camera module. After executing the command

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/rosberrypi_cam/image_raw camera:=/rosberrypi_cam
```

I am getting a half blank display without any checkerboard and the buttons are disabled. There is no X, Y and size also in the display. I am using rosberrypi_cam driver as suggested in the [page](https://github.com/japonophile/rosberrypi_cam)...

```
rosrun rosberrypi_cam rosberrypicam_node
```

I am unable to calibrate the monocular camera. Please help with a possible way out.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling in this page or with similar problems calibrating the `Camera Module v2` on the Raspberry, the answer is simple: don't do it on the Pi. Do the calibration remotely on a powerful pc.

On the Pi, just launch the capture:

```
roslaunch raspicam_node camera_module_v2_1920x1080_30fps_autocapture.launch
```

where:

```
#> cat camera_module_v2_1920x1080_30fps_autocapture.launch
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="name" default="raspicam_node" />
  <node type="raspicam_node" pkg="raspicam_node" name="$(arg name)" output="screen">

    <param name="camera_info_url" value="package://$(arg name)/camera_info/camera_module_v2_1920x1080.yaml"/>
    <param name="width" value="1920"/>
    <param name="height" value="1080"/>
    <param name="framerate" value="30"/>
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="raspicam"/>

  </node>

  <node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="start_capture" args="call --wait $(arg name)/start_capture"/>

</launch>
```

On the remote host, just change the `$ROS_MASTER_URI`, check that all the topics are exported correctly with `rostopic list` and then launch:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/raspicam_node/image_raw camera:=/raspicam_node
```